# htc desire z keeps restarting on its own

Tags: boot-loop, htc-desire-z

My HTC Desire Z keeps restarting on its own continuously, how do I stop it and how can I switch on my phone now? I tried removing the battery but that didn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: We will need some more background to help you: When did that problem start? What were your last changes (app installs, settings)? Does it boot up at all, or are we talking about a "boot-loop" here?

Comment: @Izzy Two days ago I updated candy crush. I was charging my phone 5 hours ago and it started force closing all my apps. I restarted it, but it didn't switch on, it's in a boot-loop. Also before I restarted it, it said that I was running out of free space

Comment: Thanks for the update, Rinki! I just re-tagged your question to reflect the news. For first aid, please visit the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info), that should get you out of misery. Don't forget to come back and let us know how it worked out: either [edit] your question to say where you're still stuck (and what you've tried), or answer your own question if you've been able to solve your issue. Good luck, I bet for the latter :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the information. I tried the recovery but it didn't have the 'wipe the dalvik cache' option. It didn't work. Is there any other way, or will I have to do factory reset and lose all my data?

Comment: "Wipe Dalvik" usually is only available with custom recovery (ClockworkMod, TWRP, etc.). Have you tried the safe-mode tip? Just removing the updated app then might already solve the issue.

Comment: @Izzy I tried but I can't enter safe mode on my phone, those key combinations don't work

Comment: According to [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11741530&postcount=15): *Press down the keyboard "S" key (yeah S for Safe mode) at HTC logo during boot.* As I have no Desire-Z, I cannot test myself; so please report back if that works, so I can update the tag-wiki accordingly :)

Comment: @Izzy the "S" key didn't do the job, safe mode didn't happen :(

Comment: I couldn't find any other clue either. Maybe you give the HTC service a call and asking them how to achieve that (and let us know the answer, too)?

Comment: @Izzy I sent them an email yesterday, they didn't reply yet. I will let you know when I find a solution. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Pull the battery, put it back in press `volume down +power` , it will boot into `Hboot`, then use volume to scroll down and select recovery, then restore a `backup` or flash `rom` again.

Comment: "Flash a ROM" is a nuclear option, and not generally advisable unless the OP wants it, or if there are no other options.